# Interpolate hourly load of a selected months of a year from the same months of the previous year and the next year in python pandas?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, time-series

I have the following three dataframes:

df1:

```
   date_time           system_load
01-01-2017 00:00:00    208111
01-01-2017 01:00:00    208311
01-01-2017 02:00:00    208311
01-01-2017 03:00:00    208011
  ...............       ...
31-12-2017 20:00:00    208611
31-12-2017 21:00:00    208411
31-12-2017 22:00:00    208111
31-12-2017 23:00:00    208911
```

The system load values of df1 has no problem.

df2:

```
   date_time           system_load
01-01-2018 00:00:00    208111
01-01-2018 01:00:00    208311
01-01-2018 02:00:00    208311
01-01-2018 03:00:00    208011
  ...............       ...
31-12-2018 20:00:00    209611
31-12-2018 21:00:00    209411
31-12-2018 22:00:00    209111
31-12-2018 23:00:00    209911
```

The system load values of df2 is missed starting from 06-03-2018 20:00:00 till up to 24-10-2018 22:00:00.

df3:

```
   date_time           system_load
01-01-2019 00:00:00    309119
01-01-2019 01:00:00    309391
01-01-2019 02:00:00    309811
01-01-2019 03:00:00    309711
  ...............       ...
31-12-2019 20:00:00    309611
31-12-2019 21:00:00    309411
31-12-2019 22:00:00    309111
31-12-2019 23:00:00    309911
```

The system load values of df3 has no problem.

What I want is to interpolate in suitable way the missed hourly records in df2 using the corresponding df1 and df3 hourly records (06-03-2017 20:00:00 till up to 24-10-2017 22:00:00 and 06-03-2019 20:00:00 till up to 24-10-2019 22:00:00 respectively). Based on "Pierre D"'s valuable comment I attached my scaled data.[image]

Comment: do you have a specific strategy in mind? When there is missing data, you could take the average of neighboring years (precisely 52 weeks so as to reflect weekly seasonality). However your data sample suggests that the mean for 2019 is much larger than 2018, whereas 2018 has roughly the same mean as 2017, so a mix of longitudinal variation (diff) coupled with general trend might be a better approach. Importantly, it all depends on what you want to do with the resulting data.

Comment: Thanks  "Pierre D" for your response. Your idea is amazing but how can I do it using python pandas or any way in python taking into consideration, the df1 values > df2 values >df3 values significantly.

Comment: well, it was just a question. Basically, you'd want to understand the general time-series distribution (based on the limited sample data and the term 'system_load', perhaps something like a Poisson distribution with a slowly increasing mean year-on-year). There might be special events due to certain calendar dates. In any case, once you understand the general characteristics of your time-series, then you can generate plausible data for the missing dates. So my question is: what else do you know about the data, statistically speaking?

Comment: and the more important question is: what do you want to do with the result?  Fool somebody into thinking you had no missing data to start with?... Train a ML model (then watch out for peek-ahead bias)?

Comment: Thanks "Pierre D" and I am trying to plot my data and edit my question to give me your opinion about it.

Comment: Very thanks " Mr Pierre D" . Your code is amazing and meet what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a very basic strategy that just takes data from neighboring years to fill the missing values.  The `offset` is chosen to be precisely 52 weeks, so as to reflect possible weekly seasonality.

```py
# get the whole series together, and resample to have missing data as NaN:
s = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])['system_load'].resample('H').asfreq()

offset = 52 * 7 * 24  # 52 weeks, 7 days/week, 24 hours/day
filler = pd.concat([s.shift(offset), s.shift(-offset)], axis=1).mean(axis=1)
out = s.where(~s.isna(), filler)

# optional: make a new df2 with the filled values
df2mod = out.truncate(
    before='2018',
    after=pd.Timestamp('2019') - pd.Timedelta(1)
).to_frame('system_load')
```

Notes:

- `out` contains the "filled" series for the whole `system_load` using neighboring years.
- we use `pandas.DataFrame.mean()` to build the `filler` series as the mean of the two neighboring years, in a way that takes care of `NaN` (e.g. if one year or the other has `NaN`, then the mean is the only non-NaN value).
- this is one of the most basic ways of filling the missing data, and likely won't fool a careful observer. Depending on the intended usage of the reconstructed data, a more elaborate strategy should be considered. Data reconstruction is an active field of research, and there are sophisticated methods in the literature. For example, one could use a [GAN](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generative_adversarial_network) to build a resulting series that would be very hard to discriminate from real data.