# Interpolate problem of daily time series using python pandas?

Tags: pandas, time-series

I asked before that question: Interpolate hourly load of a selected months of a year from the same months of the previous year and the next year in python pandas?
and I applied the code on Hourly time series and the result is fine but when I applied it on daily time series and change resample(H) to resample(D) or resample(W)
I got the following error:
"Only valid with DatetimeIndex, TimedeltaIndex or PeriodIndex, but got an instance of 'Index'" at the record:

```
s = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3])['system_load'].resample('W').asfreq()
```

Comment: What is the column type? Namely, your `df1['system_load'].dtype`...

Comment: Per [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html), "Object must have a datetime-like index (DatetimeIndex, PeriodIndex, or TimedeltaIndex), or pass datetime-like values to the on or level keyword."

Comment: Looking at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66931299 this post by you, you may want `s = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3]).set_index('date_time').['system_load'].resample('W').asfreq()`.

Comment: My problem is solved by applying  "df.index=pd.to_datetime(df.index)"